# Haskell - Unexpected result from nested generator in list comprehension

Tags: haskell

In this expression, x is supposed to be 1 unit larger than n. However, the resulting list is made of mostly negative numbers.

```
f :: [Integer]
f = [x-n | x <- [1,2..], n <- [0,1..]]
```

Output from `take 10 f`:

```
[1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8]
```

I expected it to be a list of 1s and I am not sure why that is not the case.

Thanks.

Comment: I get `[1,0,-1,-2,-3,-4,-5,-6,-7,-8]`, are you sure that result is really what you get?

Comment: @Noughtmare You are correct, I edited the question already. Thank you.

Comment: @Miriam: `[0,1..]` is an infinite list that contains `0`, `-1`, `-2`, `-3`, ... So it will never use the second item of the `x <- [1, 2 ..]` list.

Comment: It's not clear to me why you expect a list of ones. Can you explain *what* you aim to achieve?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm trying to take each element of x, minus each element of n. Perhaps I am misunderstanding the expression?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you give

```
f :: [Integer]
f = [x-n | x <- [1,2..], n <- [0,1..]]
```

is the imperative equivalent to

```
for x in range(1, inf):
    for n in range(0, inf):
        return x - n
```

so clearly, `x` is `1` at first, then it loops for `n` all the way up to infinity. So you get `1 - 0`, `1 - 1`, `1 - 2`, etc...

From your question I guess you want to pair elements from each list one by one instead of a nested loop. Hence, the code should be

```
zipWith (-) [1..] [0..] -- this is equal to the infinite list [1,1,1,1,...]
```

Answer (score 5):

In your definition, for each value of `x` *every* value of `n` is paired with it. For example consider

```hs
g :: [Integer]
g = [ (x, n) | x <- [1,2..4], n <- [0,1..3]]
```

The output is

```
[(1,0),(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,0),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(3,0),(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(4,0),(4,1),(4,2),(4,3)]
```

If you wanted the elements of `x` and `n` to be paired off by their respective positions then try `zip`:

```hs
f1 = [x-n | (x, n) <- zip [1,2..] [0,1..]]
```

```hs
> take 10 f1
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Willem Van Onsen mentions in the comments, your comprehension amounts to a nested loop, where the outer loop on x never moves to the next iteration. What you are seeing is thus (1 - n) for each value of n.

What you seem to need is to zip the two lists together, and then do your subtraction, like so:

```
f = map (\x -> (fst x) - snd x) $ zip [1,2..] [0,1..]
```

This will take the elements from each list pairwise and do the subtraction to give an answer of 1 as you expect.